# Operation Amplifier: + and - with equal voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier

I understand the basics of Operational Amplifiers, but I am curious, what would happen if the + and - input pins have the same voltage, does the output pin (x) give a high or a low voltage output?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCSONY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why not use the simulator and see?  Or, consider the sum of (+V) + (-1)*(+V)

Comment: It could be either high or low real op-amps have input offset errors and that multiplied by the gain could have you hitting either end stop. The simulator may not model this and assume no input offset.

Comment: @JRE, a simulator is quite likely to give a wrong answer for this question.

Comment: Yes, most simulators give a both high and low output, allowing each LED (one to + rail, one to - rail) to be powered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, in a perfect op-amp the output voltage would be mid-rail. However, due to input offset voltages the output will be somewhere between the most negative rail and the most positive rail.

OP-amps have DC gains of millions so a 100uV offset at the inputs produces an open loop output level of hundreds of volts (limited by the power rails).

As a real example, the ADA4528 has an input offset voltage that is 2.5 uV maximum at ambient temperatures. It also has an open loop gain that is at least 130 dB (3.16 million). Result is potentially an output voltage in the range +/- 8V. However it's only a 5V device so most of the time the output will be clamped to the rails. For those times that it is not against the rails the internal noises inside the op-amp will be rapidly end-stopping the output against the + and - rails.

Answer (score 1):

In a practical circuit, it would depend on the input offset voltage, Vio. The input offset voltage, which can be positive or negative, is the voltage that is added to the + pin to make it the same as the - pin. Below you can see Vio for an MCP6001.

With regards to the output voltage, your circuit will operate as a comparator. Therefore the output voltage could be 0V or +V depending on whether Vio is positive or negative.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in an ideal opamp, the output voltage will become zero if both the terminals have same voltage.since it is made out of differential amplifier, the difference between the invertng and non-inverting voltage becomes zero.

Comment: Not quite true. The op-amp has no idea where "zero" is. It knows where V+ and V- are and it knows where the inputs are. It would be better to say that it would settle somewhere around mid-supply. Welcome to EE.SE. You can improve the appearance of your answers (and your credibility) by using proper capitalisation of words where required in standard English.